# CodeJam 2014: Solution for The Repeater

Tags: string, algorithm

I participated in code jam, I successfully solved small input of [The Repeater Challenge](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2994486/dashboard) but can't seem to figure out approach for multiple strings.

Can any one give the algorithm used for multiple strings. For 2 strings ( small input ) I am comparing strings character by character and doing operations to make them equal. However this approach would time out for large input.

Can some one explain their algorithm they used. I can see solutions of other users but can't figure out what have they done.

Comment: Was this for round 1B?

Comment: @phyrrus9  Yes it was. The competition is over so I asked.

Comment: It is techniaclly over, but you shouldn't be asking, since we need to see your code to help. I personally havnt competed in round 1 yet (I plan on doing 1C), but I can take a look if you add some code. Just add a comment when youve edited (if you do).

Comment: Hint 1: We want to figure out, above all, whether 2 strings can be converted into each other *at all*. Suppose that in each string we replace all runs of the same character with a single copy of that character. If the two strings are now equal, does this tell us anything? If they are *not* equal, does this tell us anything?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I figured out way to see if we can convert. Convert multiple to single in all and check if  all equal. Don't know how to have minimum transformation count

Comment: OK then, hint 2: Notice that the 2 operations you can apply are inverses of each other -- i.e. applying one of them to a character in string 1 has the same "effect" as applying the other one to the corresponding character in string 2, insofar as the difference between the copy counts of that character between the 2 strings goes up or down by 1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker got it, maintain repetition count at each position, and moves = max-min at each position

Comment: @TejasPatel my solution is just trying all possible number for each position (1 to x , x is at most 100) I don't think the moves = max-min is correct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can tell you my solution which worked fine for both small and large inputs.
First, we have to see if there is a solution, you do that by bringing all strings to their "simplest" form. If any of them does not match, there there is no solution.

e.g.

```
aaabbbc => abc
abbbbbcc => abc
abbcca => abca
```

If only the first two were given, then a solution would be possible. As soon as the third is thrown into the mix, then it's impossible. The algorithm to do the "simplification" is to parse the string and eliminate any double character you see. As soon as a string does not equal the simplified form of the batch, bail out.

As for actual solution to the problem, i simply converted the strings to a [letter, repeat] format. So for example

```
qwerty => 1q,1w,1e,1r,1t,1y
qqqwweeertttyy => 3q,2w,3e,1r,3t,2y
```

(mind you the outputs are internal structures, not actual strings)

Imagine now you have 100 strings, you have already passed the test that there is a solution and you have all strings into the [letter, repeat] representation. Now go through every letter and find the least 'difference' of repetitions you have to do, to reach the same number. So for example

```
1a, 1a, 1a => 0 diff
1a, 2a, 2a => 1 diff
1a, 3a, 10a => 9 diff (to bring everything to 3)
```

the way to do this (i'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way) is to go from the min number to the max number and calculate the sum of all diffs. You are not guaranteed that the number will be one of the numbers in the set. For the last example, you would calculate the diff to bring everything to 1 (0,2,9 =11) then for 2 (1,1,8 =10), the for 3 (2,0,7 =9) and so on up to 10 and choose the min again. Strings are limited to 1000 characters so this is an easy calculation. On my moderate laptop, the results were instant.

Repeat the same for every letter of the strings and sum everything up and that is your solution.

Comment: +1 : by the way, I think the best number of repeats is always given by the median.

Comment: You don't need both the letter *and* the repeat, since you've already shown they share the same letters in the same order (except possibly for the repeats). The repeats alone are all that is needed at this stage.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz The median will not always be the correct choice. Consider "a","a","a","aa","aaa". Changing them all to "aa" costs 4. Changing them to "a" costs 3.

Comment: @ooga In your example, the lengths are 1,1,1,2,3 so the median is 1.  In other words, I agree that the correct choice is "a", but I also claim that it is the median?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I tried to find a counter-example but couldn't. Still, is there a proof for this?

Comment: @user2316667 Consider what happens to the cost if you increase the number of repeats by 1.  The cost will increase by 1 for every number to the left, and decrease by 1 for every number to the right.  So the cost will keep decreasing until number to left equals number to right (i.e. at the median) and then keep increasing from that point onwards.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I do not follow, sorry. What do you mean by, 'increase the number of repeats by 1'. Perhaps a concrete example: 1a,20a,30a,40a,100a. How can we prove media=30 is the number that gives the lowest number of differences, opposed to say 50 (a logical guess we might consider - ofc we KNOW after calculating it to be wrong).

Comment: @user2316667 I've added an answer with an expanded explanation of your example.

Answer (score 2):

This answer gives an example to explain why finding the median number of repeats produces the lowest cost.

Suppose we have values:

```
1 20 30 40 100
```

And we are trying to find the value which has shortest total distance to all these values.

We might guess the best answer is 50, with cost |50-1|+|50-20|+|50-30|+|50-40|+|50-100| = 159.

Split this into two sums, left and right, where left is the cost of all numbers to the left of our target, and right is the cost of all numbers to the right.

```
left = |50-1|+|50-20|+|50-30|+|50-40| = 50-1+50-20+50-30+50-40 = 109
right = |50-100| = 100-50 = 50
cost = left + right = 159
```

Now consider changing the value by x.  Providing x is small enough such that the same numbers are on the left, then the values will change to:

```
left(x) = |50+x-1|+|50+x-20|+|50+x-30|+|50+x-40| = 109 + 4x
right(x) = |50+x-100| = 50 - x
cost(x) = left(x)+right(x) = 159+3x
```

So if we set x=-1 we will decrease our cost by 3, therefore the best answer is not 50.

The amount our cost will change if we move is given by difference between the number to our left (4) and the number to our right (1).

Therefore, as long as these are different we can always decrease our cost by moving towards the median.

Therefore the median gives the lowest cost.

If there are an even number of points, such as 1,100 then all numbers between the two middle points will give identical costs, so any of these values can be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Since Thanasis already explained the solution, I'm providing here my source code in Ruby. It's really short (only 400B) and following his algorithm exactly.

```
def solve(strs)
    form = strs.first.squeeze
    strs.map { |str|
        return 'Fegla Won' if form != str.squeeze
        str.chars.chunk { |c| c }.map { |arr|
            arr.last.size
        }
    }.transpose.map { |row|
        Range.new(*row.minmax).map { |n|
            row.map { |r|
                (r - n).abs
            }.reduce :+
        }.min
    }.reduce :+
end

gets.to_i.times { |i|
    result = solve gets.to_i.times.map { gets.chomp }
    puts "Case ##{i+1}: #{result}"
}
```

It uses a method `squeeze` on strings, which removes all the duplicate characters. This way, you just compare every squeezed line to the reference (variable `form`). If there's an inconsistency, you just return that **Fegla Won**.

Next you use a `chunk` method on char array, which collects all consecutive characters. This way you can count them easily.